# How to throw OptimisticLockException with hibernate-jpa2.0

Tags: java, jpa-2.0, jboss7.x, optimistic-locking

I'm currently working on an optimistic-locking management in my project.
We use JPA 2.0 (hibernate-jpa2.0-api-1.0.1.Final) and the datasource is provided by JBoss 7.

**What I did**

In my entity "AccordSimple" I use the @Version annotation:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "AccordSimple")
public class AccordSimple {
    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "parametresubsidesequence", 
        sequenceName = "parametresubsidesequence", allocationSize = 1)  
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "parametresubsidesequence")
    private Long id;

    // Optimistic lock.
    @Version
    private Long version;

}
```

And this is my AccordServiceImpl

```
public AccordDTO updateAccord(AccordDTO accordDTO) throws AppException {

    AccordSimple accord = getAccordRepository().findByReference(
            accordDTO.getAccordReference());

    if (accord == null) {
        return null;
    }

    // copy new values from the DTO...
    accord.setVariable(accordDTO.getVariable());
    // ... 

    // Set the version from the DTO (old version if someone changes before me!)
    accord.setVersion(accordDTO.getVersion());

    getAccordRepository().merge(accord);
    return accordDTO;
}
```

With that, no OptimisticLockException will be threw. Even if the version contained in accord juste before the merge is under the version in my DB.

I have found the reason of that. This is the responsible:

```
    AccordSimple accord = getAccordRepository().findByReference(
            accordDTO.getAccordReference());
```

Because if I change my method to:

```
public AccordDTO updateAccord(AccordDTO accordDTO) throws AppException {

    AccordSimple accord = new AccordSimple(accordDTO.getAccordReference(), accordDTO.getVersion());

    // copy new values from the DTO...
    accord.setVariable(accordDTO.getVariable());
    // ... 

    // Set the version from the DTO (old version if someone changes before me!)
    accord.setVersion(accordDTO.getVersion());

    getAccordRepository().merge(accord);
    return accordDTO;
}
```

An OptimisticLockException will be threw!

**The problem**

The version comes from the Hibernate cache and not from my DTO.
So if I detach the entity then everything will work (I guess) but I don't want to do that (source of bugs if a developper forget it...).

Have you any idea?

Answer (score 1):

[Edited]
A possible alternative:
Haven't tried that yet, you may have a try:

Keep an extra version number in entity, by using @PostLoad or extra column mapping with insertable=false,updateable=false.

Have a @PreUpdate method do the checking on the version field and the extra-version field.  If they don't match, throw the exception.

All these can be put in the base model class.  So no one will forget to put the logic in the entity  :)

---

(original message)

This is exactly what I faced in my previous project.  Hibernate is not looking into the version field in the entity when performing the optimistic lock verification.

The way I solved that time is by verifying myself when "merging" the DTO to the entity.  At that time, I am having a utility to map properties between DTO and Entity.  Version check is just a matter of an extra annotation in the version field in DTO, instead of setting the value to corresponding entity's property, I am throwing an exception when it is not matching.

Probably not applicable to you though

---

Comment: Indeed it's not applicable ;-)

Comment: Your solution with PostLoad and PreUpdate annotations works well but I don't know if it's the best solution.